# Java Converting: char[] array --> String

Tags: java, string, char

How do you convert a character array to a String?

I have this code

```
Console c = System.console();
if (c == null) {
    System.err.println("No console.");
    System.exit(1);
}
char [] password = c.readPassword("Enter your password: ");
```

I need to convert that to a String so I can verify

```
if(stringPassword == "Password"){
    System.out.println("Valid");
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There is a [reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords) `char[]` is used for passwords over `String`s.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `String(char[])` constructor.

```
char [] password = c.readPassword("Enter your password: ");
String stringPassword = new String(password);
```

And when you compare, don't use `==`, use `.equals():

```
if(stringPassword.equals("Password")){
```

Comment: You should also add in the bit about not using `==` to compare string's equality.

Comment: Thanks, was in the middle of editing when you posted comment.

Comment: and as a best practice, if your comparing a variable with a string literal or a constant, always call the .equals method from the string literal or a constant to avoid possible null pointer exception, i.e. "Password".equals(stringPassword)

Comment: Thanks guys. :) I will accept your answer in 8 minutes when it allows me :D

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to make a `new String` out of the `char[]`. Then you'll want to compare them using the `.equals()` method, not `==`.

So instead of

```
if(stringPassword == "Password"){
```

You get

```
if("password".equals(new String(stringPassword))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not as efficient you could always use a for loop:

```
char [] password = c.readPassword("Enter your password: ");
String str = "";

for(i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
    str += password[i];
}
```

This is a very simple way and requires no previous knowledge of functions/classes in the standard library!

Comment: Not only that, but char[] is preferred for passwords anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords